# How to copy only certain files and subdirectories

Tags: bash, rsync

Hi let's say I have a directory like this:

```
/
    my_work
               /dir1
                    keepdir1.ddd
                    keepdir2.ddd
                    file.cfg
                    (lots of files and directories I don't want)
               /dir2
                    (same layout as dir 1)
```

So I want to copy the directory "my_work" and all of the "dir1", "dir2", etc sub directories.  But within each of those I want to keep only certain files, and certain directories. In the directories I keep I want to recursively include everything.

Here's what I've tried so far but nothing seems to copy:

```
rsync -rl --include-from=~/rsync_include /my_work ~/backup
```

And the contents of rsync_include are:

```
+ *file.cfg
+ *keepdir*/*
- *
```

Comment: Well is there a commonality to the files you want to exclude, so that wildcards could be used?  If not, then you have to just list them all in the include file.

Comment: Yeah, I think I could use wildcards but can a directory be a wildcard?  Will it know to copy the matching directory recursively and not apply the exclude * inside a match directory?  That's my confusion in a nutshell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you forgot to provide important information, the following script will work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for DIR in my_work/* ; do
    mkdir -pv dest/"$DIR"
    cp -av "$DIR"/*.cfg "$DIR"/keepdir* dest/"$DIR"
done
```

Sample output, with non-applicable wildcards producing messages:

```
dest
dest/my_work
dest/my_work/dir1
my_work/dir1/file.cfg -> dest/my_work/dir1/file.cfg
my_work/dir1/keepdir1.ddd -> dest/my_work/dir1/keepdir1.ddd
my_work/dir1/keepdir2.ddd -> dest/my_work/dir1/keepdir2.ddd
dest/my_work/dir2
my_work/dir2/file.cfg -> dest/my_work/dir2/file.cfg
cp: my_work/dir2/keepdir*: No such file or directory
dest/my_work/dir3
cp: my_work/dir3/*.cfg: No such file or directory
cp: my_work/dir3/keepdir*: No such file or directory
```

Comment: That's perfect!  Thanks so much.  That's way easier than fooling with rsync!